# How to add current Time(HH:MM:SS) to NSDate?

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7, nsdate

I am using https://github.com/ruslanskorb/RSDayFlow to add calendar to my application.

I override the method as

```
// Prints out the selected date.
- (void)datePickerView:(RSDFDatePickerView *)view didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date {

    self.transactionDate = date;
    self.inputDateField.text =  [[Helper getDateFormatterForClient] stringFromDate:self.transactionDate];
    NSLog(@"transactionDate=%@", self.transactionDate);
    [self.inputDateField resignFirstResponder];

}
```

All I want to add is current time `HH:MM:SS` to the `date` user selects.

I have no idea how to do this, any help is greatly appreciated

**UPDATE**

Currently, when the date is selected, I get

```
2015-01-15 10:34:35.210 myapp-ios[21476:60b] transactionDate=2015-01-15 08:00:00 +0000
```

Comment: Does `date`'s HH:MM:SS = 00:00:00?

Comment: Yes, I just updated my question @LyndseyScott

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSCalendar_Class/ https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDateComponents_Class/

Comment: In short: you could create `NSDateComponents` from selected date and `NSDateComponents` from current date (i.e. `[NSDate date]`). Then overwrite h:m:s components and create a new `NSDate` from the lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If by "current time HH:MM:SS to the date" you mean that you want to *replace* the selected date's HH:MM:SS with the current HH:MM:SS, you can extract the relevant date components from the selected date, get the current datetime, extract the relevant time components, then add those components back into `self.transactionDate`, ex:

```
// Prints out the selected date.
- (void)datePickerView:(RSDFDatePickerView *)view didSelectDate:(NSDate *)date {

    self.transactionDate = date;
    self.inputDateField.text =  [[Helper getDateFormatterForClient] stringFromDate:self.transactionDate];
    NSLog(@"transactionDate=%@", self.transactionDate);
    [self.inputDateField resignFirstResponder];

    // Create an instance of the current calendar
    NSCalendar *calendar = [NSCalendar currentCalendar];

    // Break self.transactionDate into day, month, and year components
    NSDateComponents* dateComponents = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] components:NSCalendarUnitYear|
        NSCalendarUnitMonth|NSCalendarUnitDay fromDate:self.transactionDate];

    // Save transaction date with just the day, month, and year
    self.transactionDate = [[NSCalendar currentCalendar] dateFromComponents:dateComponents];

    // Get the current datetime
    NSDate *currentDate = [NSDate date];

    // Extract the hour, minute, and second components
    NSDateComponents *components = [calendar components:(NSCalendarUnitHour|
        NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:currentDate];

    // Add those hour, minute, and second components to
    // self.transactionDate
    self.transactionDate = [calendar dateByAddingComponents:components 
        toDate:self.transactionDate options:0];

}
```

Comment: Another less efficient but conceptually simpler way to do it would be to format both date and time separately, combine the strings, then parse the result into an NSDate.

Comment: Thank you @Lyndsey, I was confused in using NSDate, NSDateComponents and NSCalendar together.

Answer (score 0):

This method Which I have created the in the category of `NSDate'.

```
+ (NSDate *)getDateWithCurrentTime:(NSDate *)date {

    NSCalendar *gregorian = [[NSCalendar alloc]
                             initWithCalendarIdentifier:NSCalendarIdentifierGregorian];


    NSDateComponents *components =
    [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitDay |
                           NSCalendarUnitYear|NSCalendarUnitMonth) fromDate:date];


    NSDateComponents *CurrentDateComponent =
    [gregorian components:(NSCalendarUnitHour |
                           NSCalendarUnitMinute|NSCalendarUnitSecond) fromDate:[NSDate date]];

    [components setHour:[CurrentDateComponent hour]];
    [components setMinute:[CurrentDateComponent minute]];
    [components setSecond:[CurrentDateComponent second]];
    [components setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone systemTimeZone]];

    return [gregorian dateFromComponents:components];

}
```